# Removing rows when reading data D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Say I have a sample file sample.csv:

```
row,col,value
1,1,2
1,2,3
1,3,NA
```

When reading data in d3 you do something like:

```
d3.csv("sample.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
});
```

However, for the NA value +d.value will return NaN. How can I exclude NaN values from my data. i.e. read the data, and only take rows which have a number value

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `isNaN` on the data before you try to add it:

```
d3.csv('sample.csv', function(data) {
    data = data.filter(function(d){
        if(isNaN(d.value)){
            return false;
        }
        d.value = parseInt(d.value, 10);
        return true;
    });
});
```

This assumes your numbers will all be base-10 integers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I dont want to keep the row if the value is not numeric. I only want rows with non NaN values. Your solution will keep the row but replacing the numeric value with an empty string

Comment: Ah, in that case you'll want to use something like `.filter` instead of `.forEach`. I'll edit my answer.