# Remove NaN values from data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here's my code:

```
d3.csv('stockdataToPlot.csv', function(d){
  return {date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.Date), aapl : d.AAPL,
          aapl_sma: d.SMA_AAPL, tsla : d.TSLA, tsla_sma: d.SMA_TSLA}
}).then(plot_data);
```

I would like to remove the NaN values from `d.SMA_AAPL` and `d.SMA_TSLA`
I would appreciate if someone helped me incorporate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922236/removing-rows-when-reading-data-d3/12922313) example properly:

```
d3.csv('stockdataToPlot.csv', function(d){
  var data = d.filter(function(e){
        if(isNaN(e.value)){
            return false;
        }
        e.value = parseInt(e.value, 10);
        return true;
    });
  return {date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.Date), aapl : d.AAPL,
          aapl_sma: data.SMA_AAPL, tsla : d.TSLA, tsla_sma: data.SMA_TSLA}
}).then(plot_data);
```

The current error is `TypeError: d.filter is not a function`. Which is confusing because .filter takes a data array as a parameter, which should be `d` as referenced in the first line.

This is a nice compact line of code from the documentation:
`const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);` How is this adapted?
`var data = d.filter(?? => ??.isNan(??));`?

I'm sure I'm overthinking this, but I'm new to javascript and I don't fully understand how this works. In python pandas I'd just do `data.dropna()` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```
d3.csv('stockdataToPlot.csv', function(d){
  function removeNaN(e,c){
    if(e>0){return e}else{return c}
  }
  return {date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.Date), aapl : d.AAPL,
          aapl_sma: removeNaN(+d.SMA_AAPL,d.AAPL), tsla : d.TSLA, tsla_sma: removeNaN(+d.SMA_TSLA,d.TSLA)}
}).then(plot_data);
```

In my case the NaN was registering as "" which defaults to 0 when passed through with a +. Luckily I didn't have any values in my data less than or equal to 0. Instead of removing I replaced them with the same values as the close since it's just a moving average. It's not ideal but it's okay for now.